# C macro stringifying a variable

Tags: c, string, macros

When can I pass variable's value to a macro for stringifying?

For example the code taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301451/1714692) works with a constant-defined macro.

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x

{
  ...
  char word[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];     
  scanf("%" STRINGIFY(MAX_STRING_LENGTH) "s", word);
  ...
}
```

However I cannot use it with a variable such as:

```
{
  ...
  int val = 20;
  char word[MAX_STRING_LENGTH+1];     
  scanf("%" STRINGIFY(val) "s", word);
  ...
}
```

since the compilation is successful with this warning:

```
warning: invalid conversion specifier 'v' [-Wformat-invalid-specifier]
    scanf("%" STRINGIFY(var) "s", word);
           ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
test2.c:4:22: note: expanded from macro 'STRINGIFY'
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
                     ^
test2.c:5:23: note: expanded from macro 'STRINGIFY2'
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x
                      ^
<scratch space>:466:2: note: expanded from here
"var"
 ^
1 warning generated
```

but the run of the code does not wait for any input.

On the contrary in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14351971/1714692) it was possible to pass a variable to this macro:

```
#define PRINT(int) printf(#int "%d\n",int)
...
int var =8;
PRINT(var);
```

What is the difference between the two cases? How can I modify the first one so that it accepts also variables?

I tried using `%d` inside the macro but I was not successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The preprocessor always operates on tokens only.

A macro is not a function. You don't pass it a variable (by value). You pass a token sequence. In `STRINGIFY(MAX_STRING_LENGTH)` the token sequence is `MAX_STRING_LENGTH`, and in `STRINGIFY(val)` it's the token sequence `val`.

`MAX_STRING_LENGTH` is itself a macro, and due to how `STRINGIFY` is defined to work, the macro will be expanded by the preprocessor before turning it a string literal. So `20` is in turn the token which gets `#` applied to it, and it produces `"20"` as a string literal.

On the other hand `val` is not a macro, the preprcosseor is not going to expand it. It's going to keep the token sequence as `val`. The fact `val` is the name of a variable with some value means *nothing* to the preprocessor, it only cares about tokens. So `val` is transformed into the literal `"val"`.

The example you brought from another post worked because it expanded to this:

```
printf("var" "%d\n", var);
```

The variable name in `#int` turns into a literal, there is no magic that lets the preprocessor read a variable's value. The fact `var 8` is printed is only because `var` is passed as an argument to `printf`! It's printed at run-time by the `%d` specifier.

Finally, when experimenting with the preprcoessor it's always helpful to look at the source file after prpeprocessing is done, but before the file is compiled. The `gcc -E` flag (or equivalent for your compiler) can help you do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there/do you know any work-around with macros to generate a string in the form `%20s` (something like maybe `"%%%ds", var`) to be passed then to a function like `scanf`?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - There is actually. It's in the [specification of `printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). You can use `%*s`. The `*` means the width is passed as an extra argument. I.e. `"%*s", val, word`

Comment: @StoryTeller But that's for printf only, scanf does not support this (unfortunately!)...

Comment: @Aconcagua - Nobody asked about `scanf`, but it does support `*` as the percision of `s`. I.e. `%.*s` (note the dot). The precision of `s` means the maximum buffer width.

Comment: @StoryTeller See question: `scanf("%" STRINGIFY(val) "s", word);`

Comment: And so does `printf` matter of fact. Since the OP wanted "maximum" length, they probably want to use precision there too. Consulting the docs is prudent on this.

Comment: @Aconcagua - I did "see the question", thank you very much. There is another issue here, with the OP not being aware that `"%20s"` should be `"%.20s"`. But that is beside the point about the preprocessor.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh, need to admit, overlooked that missing period myself, too... But as far as I interprete the question, that would be exactly what OP seeks for: `scanf("%.*s", val, word);` - which actually is what I have missed myself so often, too...

Comment: @Aconcagua - Dammit. I shouldn't be flapping my gums. There is no standard `.*` for scanf. Now I'm gonna be bothered all day until I figure out where I learned of that extension.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - Unlike my confused self told you, if you want a portable way to scan a string with the ability to specify buffer length dynamically... `scanf` is not the way to go.

Comment: Yeah I was trying it `scanf("%.*s", val, word)`: it runs but does not write to the buffer. As for the question, it was to understand better macros: how they work and how to use them. The reason was exactly to implement a secure `scanf` with a dynamic length of buffer (I know there are other posts but wanted to explore also this way) but I didn't want to make the question general so I did not put any emphasis on it. For this reason anything is well accepted :). So `scanf("%.*s", val, word)` doesn't work: does it?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi No, it doesnt't, at least not with standard C.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - Nope. Scanf does not support dynamic buffer length specification. If you are on a POSIX system then you could use `%ms`. That will use malloc internally to allocate the buffer (and you need to pass the address of a pointer to assign to), but it's POSIX only, again.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! very helpful

Comment: I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54461111/1714692. Apparently not even all POSIX systems, i.e. OSX, support that usage of `scanf`.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - POSIX is a standard. And OSX does not conform. That sucks, yeah

Comment: Actually formally it conforms (or should): it is  POSIX system.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi - To claim one conforms and to do so can be a world apart. I mean, questions pop up on SO about compiler conformance all the time :)

Answer (score 3):

`STRINGIFY(val)` will result in `"val"`, not the value you wanted to stringify, so you get a final format string of `"%vals"` (`"%" "val" "s"`). That's how the C preprocessor works, it does just text replacements, nothing more.

The `PRINT` example:

```
#define PRINT(int) printf(#int "%d\n", int)

PRINT(var);                // to be resolved
printf(#var  "%d\n", var); // intermediate result
printf("var" "%d\n", var); // final result, this is what the C compiler sees
```

But why did it work with `MAX_STRING_LENGTH`?

```
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 20
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY2(x)
#define STRINGIFY2(x) #x

STRINGIFY(MAX_STRING_LENGTH)  // to be resolved
STRINGIFY2(20)                // intermediate step; STRINGIFY2 known as macro, thus:
#20                           // another intermediate step
"20"                          // final result
```