# scanf("%ms", &p) not working on OSX system

Tags: c, macos, malloc, scanf, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to use `scanf("%ms, &p)` function in the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    int n;

    n = scanf("%ms", &p);
    if (n == 1) {
      printf("read: %s\n", p);
      free(p);
    }
    else {
      printf( "%d, No matching characters\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This should allocate memory dynamically avoiding buffer overflow. The syntax `%ms` should be for POSIX systems. However on OSX (High Sierra), this is not working: the code is executed, the `scanf` result is 0 and it does not stop the program to wait for user input.

If I do:

```
if (n == 0) {
  printf("read: %s\n", p);
  free(p);
}
```

I see there is the following error in `malloc`:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeeb91f9c8: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Why is that?

Comment: On my linux system, "man scanf" seems to suggest you should use "%as" (or possibly %s$a ,- its not too clear) but is a GNU extension.

Comment: sorry I tried `%ms` first and that should have been the original question: my bad. Anyway `mc` `ms` are not working. `as` stops asking for input (there is a warning though: `format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]` and it does not print the string back

Comment: The `m` specifier was added to [POSIX.1-2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/help/codes.html#CX): "The functionality described is an extension to the ISO C standard. Application developers may make use of an extension as it is supported on all POSIX.1-2017-conforming systems."  Given that POSIX.1-2017 is actually copyrighted in 2018, it would be somewhat difficult for OS X High Sierra, released in September 2017, to be compliant.

Comment: @SimonF: `%as` is absolutely wrong. It would scan for a floating point number, expecting a `double *` arg for the address to store it to, then expect a literal `'s'`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It was not added in "POSIX 2017", but has been present since POSIX 2008. The 2017 edition is just minor bugfixes.

Comment: @R.. The man page does say  *"This is a GNU extension; C99 employs the 'a' character as a conversion specifier (and it can also be used as such in the GNU implementation)."*   I THINK there has to be a "$" symbol in there as well.. but I've not tried myself.

Answer (score 3):

The manual page for`scanf()` et al for macOS does not mention support for the feature.  It isn’t implemented. It is a nuisance.  The support for POSIX on macOS is occasionally frustratingly behind the times.

Comment: It is supposed to be a POSIX feature and OSX is a POSIX system isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to the real world.  Systems are imperfect.  It annoys me, but there isn’t much I can do about it.  Unfortunately, you still have to read the local manual pages to check what’s supported. There’s the theory (POSIX 2008 as updated) and the practice (macOS 10.14.3 Mojave), and they’re different.

Comment: Well ok... wanted to understand IF I was doing something wrong or not.

Comment: To be fair, High Sierra seems to predate the adoption of POSIX.1-2017, which appears to be when the `m` was added to POSIX.

Comment: The `%ms` feature was added much longer ago than the 2017 revision. I believe it was in the original 2008 version, but it might have been added in a later amendment, but definitely not as late as 2017.  It’s been a nuisance to me much longer than that, @AndrewHenle.

Comment: @FrancescoBoi: OSX lacks support for almost everything past POSIX 2001. Lack of working semaphores (they crash and corrupt memory rather than just not being present) is probably the most infamous example.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Indeed it was in 2008. 2017 is a TC, and TCs are not permitted to add new functionality like that.